# Equivalent of Scala some and none in Spark Java API

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have written a mapToPair function in a Spark Java API project. I need to have a functionality similar to Scala None and Some so it maybe for a particular map I don't return anything (None in scala)

```
JavaPairRDD<DateTime,Row> sensorDataDoubleRDD= sensorDataDoubleDF.toJavaRDD().mapToPair(new PairFunction<Row,DateTime,Row>() 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8355799038879757766L;
    @Override
    public Tuple2<DateTime,Row> call(Row row) {

        //return new Tuple2("s",1);
        return null;    
    }
});

System.out.println("the count is: "+sensorDataDoubleRDD.count());
```

For example, running the above code always returns a positive count value, not 0.

Comment: if you have java 8, your existing code could be reduced to:
`JavaPairRDD<DateTime,Row> sensorDataDoubleRDD= sensorDataDoubleDF.toJavaRDD().mapToPair(x->null);`. If you want to stick to java, at least use java 8 which supports lamda expressions.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 8 you can use Optional which is some how similar to Option in scala. You can follow [here](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/08/optional-in-java-8-cheat-sheet.html) for more.

Or you can create Some object by new Some(data) and None by scala.None$.MODULE$ since None is a singleton.